# Responsive Design with media queries not switching

Tags: css, media-queries

Good afternoon,

I am trying to make a website of mine responsive but i can't get it to work. I have been googling for about an hour or 3 and i am almost sure i am not doing it wrong but yet it does not work.

Here is my code:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1230px) { 
}

@media screen and (min-width: 750px) and (max-width: 1229px) {

    body{
    display: none;
    }
}
```

the best way i can best describe the problem is when i visit my website with browser in fullscreen it loads normally like i want it to but when i shrink the window it should load the other part of the css but just doesn't load any css. i putted display:none in there so that the page is white to see if it works.

I have 
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />`
in my html.

Url of the site: http://www.biebvragen.nl

Comment: Can you please link us your website to have the example?

Comment: @Supamiu Yes sure ill add the url in the post

Comment: your code is working well i cant see any problem, it is resposive

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if a allowed to answer my own question but it works now!

Instead of:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1230px) { 
}

@media screen and (min-width: 750px) and (max-width: 1229px) {

body{
display: none;
}
}
```

I changed it to:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 750px) and (max-width: 1229px) {

body{
display: none;
}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1230px) { 
}
```

And it seems to work fine now!

Answer (score 0):

It works well with iceweasel on my linux, try with another browser or do a Ctrl + F5 refresh.

Maybe cleaning your cache can be the solution too, but your code works well, it's not a css problem, or it shouldn't work on my browser too.

Comment: tried all my browsers Firfox chrome and safari same issue on all. Do you see a completely white screen?

Comment: i see a completely white screen when i go in low resolution, and i see "Deze website is niet beschikbaar op deze resolutie. " if i go on very low resolution.

Comment: Yes that is what its supposed to do :)! works for me to now switched the order around in my css